# Ticketing Gem in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to know if there is a basic ticketing gem available in Rails 3 which can be used to track customer issues in a rails application. Tickets can have status such as : Open, Resolved, Closed etc.

I am also looking at leveraging boiler plate views/UI in any such gem and make some tweaks/changes as per my requirement so that the work of writing UI code is also reduced.

I checked ruby gems library but didn't find any active gem for the same.

Can anyone give some suggestions on this?

Comment: Did you try looking on ruby toolbox? https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ticket

Comment: Also, just because something isn't actively developed doesn't necessarily mean it's no good. Some libraries just tend to reach their logical conclusion and go into maintenance mode.

Comment: Not sure if you want something open source or commercial but commercially you can check out zendesk and uservoice.  There are many instances of live sites using these services and both have nice integrations prewritten where you can integrate rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I will try TicGit and other gems.

Answer (score 0):

I use Lighthouse. The API is not great but it gets the job done. The gem is called lighthouse-api.